# Control size and screen location of an existing instance of Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, activex

I need to be able to control the browser size and location for my site once it opens in the browser.

I'm assuming I can do this via javascript in the body load event.

I've tried this

```
var ie;
ie = new ActiveXObject("InternetExplorer.Application");
ie.Top = 1;
ie.Left = 1;
```

and it does nothing even though

```
alert(ie.Top);
alert(ie.Left);
```

returns 1 for each property.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do positioning to any docked Element. Window in full mode cannot be moved. Using javascript, you can open another window and control the position and size of child.